# SQL Query to get the next sal in same line

Tags: sql

```
Employee Salary Department
A 1000 IT
B 2000 IT
C 3000 IT
D 4000 HR
E 2000 HR
F 1500 IT
G 7000 HR
```

Write a query to get results like below -
Employee Salary Next highest salary(in same department)

```
Department
A         1000            1500                              IT
B         1500            2000                              IT
.
.
E         2000            4000                              HR
D         4000            None                              HR
```

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: You need to show some effort here.  What have you tried?

Comment: The query is going to depend on the platform you are using.  Is this for SQL Server, Oracle, MySql etc.

Comment: SQL Server. But I want to lean for other platform also.

Answer (score 0):

```
select employee, salary
    , lead(salary) over(partition by department order by salary) as next_salary
    , department
from table
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.